# increase the performance in ie 11 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

- I am trying to increase the performance in ie 11 browser

  - when i save a record in ie11 browser it takes around 25 seconds
  - but when i save a record in chrome browser it takes around only 3
    seconds
  - I did profiling in ie11 browser, found that in sportsRenderExecuted
    function  the inclusive time is 4000ms
  - where as in chrome browser its 600ms
  - providing the code below, can you tell me how to fix it
  - do i need to change any js functionality\

Code:

```
  sportsSave: function (basicForm, action, choices) {

    var sportsArguments = choices.sportsArguments;
    var sportsPage = sportsArguments.sportsPage;
```

Comment: Try benchmarking the time for `Ext.decode(xhr.responseText)` with the expected data in each of your browsers.  Perhaps IE is really poor at parsing JSON?  Also, what does `queryByParticularKey()` do since you are calling that a lot?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry its queryById http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-queryById i have updated my code in fiddle, can u add your ext,decode confused http://jsfiddle.net/669su0hd/

Comment: @jfriend00 I found the solution it takes more time for setVisible but the problem is can you tell me where to add the suspendKLayouts and resumeLayouts in my code https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?214492-internet-explorer-very-slow-with-setVisible

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the similar problem. Conceling the page layout helped me improve the performance drastically

```
{
        Ext.suspendLayouts();
        // batch of updates
        Ext.resumeLayouts(true); 
}
```

also refer [performance tunning](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-performance/)

Hope this helps